# Optimalization, plan comparision

Tags: numerical-methods, linear-programming

Let's say there are two tariff plan options of a provider offering internet access and landline telephony.

Option 1: DSL flatrate, landline flatrate : 29,95 \$

Option 2: DSL flatrate: 24,95 \$ , landline: 0,029 $ per minute

Now, I figured out by trying and approximating, that option 1 would be cheaper starting from 173 Minutes/month but how would be the correct mathematical approach?

Comment: Spingo, cambap boo gonderko. Flimnap, carplay timpfee gombarpee, clabnap foolshtang clar ig nippo ig hop. Shpley, nip ig nip og gorn fle minhoppo, glib ganib carnhoo flippo, flimnap flimnoop flimnop. Fill-ging, glarpa nop ig homp, carnapee dombee dombah fornhorfyhoffy clanhippo. Shnarlong, ligamone ganerpy clomb ig nop big. Flerp, plerf flrep plifor contop. Poonoogloohoo terppy, trip ganip gom bop fowl hop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**hint**: $29.95 \leq 24.95 + 0.029x$